# Why would Document Library templates not show in create view?

Tags: 2010, document-library, list-template

We recently upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to 2010. There are a number of customization we made in the environment, and it seems that something is causing a problem when a user tries to create a document library based on a template (.stp).  Here is the scenario:

A user saves a list as a template. It shows up in the List Template Gallery (_catalogs/lt) as expected. The user then goes to create a new list (_layouts/create.aspx or the Silverlight counterpart). The list shows up and the user is able to create new instances of the list.

When the user tried to do the the same things with a document library, it does get saved to the List Template Gallery, but **does not** show up when creating a new document library.

I tried this process on a clean install of SP2010 and it works fine with document libraries. I tried downloading the .stp file created from the clean environment and uploading into the tempalte gallery in our custom environment, and it doesn't show up either.

Another note of interest is that if I generate the URL for creating a new instance of the list manually, by filling in the template's name and featureID into /_layouts/new.aspx?CustomTemplate=test%20template%20lib%2Estp&FeatureId={...}&ListTemplate=101 everything seems to work fine. So the only thing that's not working is that the user can't see the option on _layouts/create.aspx or the Silverlight counterpart.

What could cause this type of behavior?

**UPDATE:** Did some more troubleshooting and figured out that this only happens on upgraded sites. If we create a new subsite under the upgraded site, it has no trouble seeing all the list and doc lib templates from the gallery. Even ones saved from the patent site.

Answer (score 1):

Could you see what's in the STP file? Just download it and rename to .cab.

I suspect the fact that this happens only in upgraded sites might have something to do with an invalid schema or something like that, maybe sharepoint uses leftover SP2007 (schema) artifacts to create the .stp file, which the create list page / control might not understand.

Comment: I've tried looking inside the STP, but at this point have ruled out the possibility of the template being an issue (unless we see evidence to the contrary) because on the subsite, all items from the template gallery are available. So we're trying to figure out how create.aspx decides what to pull in what not to.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't think you can use a SP 2007 STP file in SP 2010.  I think you will need to create a new SP 2010 .wsp file as the document library template.

Comment: All of this is happening in 2010. The fact that we upgraded from 2007 is just background info. Also, list templates still use STP files. Site templates are the ones which are now WSP.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  So you are saving the list template from 2010 not reusing one from 2007?

Comment: Yes. It's all in the 2010 environment. On the same site where the template is created.

Comment: Figured out that this only happens on upgraded sites. Adding more details to the question.